# Install MySQL 8 and rabbitmq in an Ubuntu 18 docker image

Tags: mysql, docker, rabbitmq, ubuntu-18.04

I have a Dockerfile with `ubuntu 18.04` base image and python3.8 installed.
I want to Install the following Services on top of the said Ubuntu 18.04 Image:

- `MySQl 8.0`
- `RabbitMQ (Management plugin enabled)`

I have a solution with docker-compose running the aforementioned as separate services. But, I need to create a custom image with the above services inside `ubuntu 18.04`

So far all I've been able to achieve is an Ubuntu image with rabitmq but have not been able to install `mysql 8`.

*Dockerfile:*

```
...

FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN adduser --system --group --no-create-home mysql
RUN adduser --group --home /home/rabbitmq rabbitmq

ENV MYSQL_USER=mysql \
    MYSQL_VERSION=5.7 \
    MYSQL_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/mysql \
    MYSQL_RUN_DIR=/run/mysqld \
    MYSQL_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mysql

RUN : \
    && apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        software-properties-common \
    && add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        python3.8-venv \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        supervisor \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        gcc ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 netcat pkg-config curl apt-transport-https gosu gnupg debconf-utils  \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      mysql-server=${MYSQL_VERSION}* \
    && curl -fsSL https://github.com/rabbitmq/signing-keys/releases/download/2.0/rabbitmq-release-signing-key.asc | apt-key add - \

    && rm -rf ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR} \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && gosu nobody true


RUN python3.8 -m venv /venv
ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor /etc/supervisor/conf.d
COPY supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisor.conf

COPY ./setup/docker/mysql/create_database.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql
COPY ./setup/docker/mysql/dataplatform.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2.sql

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
COPY mysql-entrypoint.sh /mysql-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /mysql-entrypoint.sh
COPY rabbit_entrypoint.sh /rabbit_entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /rabbit_entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
EXPOSE 3306 15672 9001
CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisor.conf"]
```

*Here is my mysql-entrypoint.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

[[ $DEBUG == true ]] && set -x

DB_NAME=${DB_NAME:-"dataplatform activiti_db"}
DB_USER=${DB_USER:-}
DB_PASS=${DB_PASS:-}

DB_REMOTE_ROOT_NAME=${DB_REMOTE_ROOT_NAME:-}
DB_REMOTE_ROOT_PASS=${DB_REMOTE_ROOT_PASS:-}
DB_REMOTE_ROOT_HOST=${DB_REMOTE_ROOT_HOST:-"127.0.0.1"}

MYSQL_CHARSET=${MYSQL_CHARSET:-"utf8"}
MYSQL_COLLATION=${MYSQL_COLLATION:-"utf8_unicode_ci"}

create_data_dir() {
  mkdir -p ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR}
  chmod -R 0700 ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR}
  chown -R ${MYSQL_USER}:${MYSQL_USER} ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR}
}

create_run_dir() {
  mkdir -p ${MYSQL_RUN_DIR}
  chmod -R 0755 ${MYSQL_RUN_DIR}
  chown -R ${MYSQL_USER}:root ${MYSQL_RUN_DIR}

  # hack: remove any existing lock files
  rm -rf ${MYSQL_RUN_DIR}/mysqld.sock.lock
}

create_log_dir() {
  mkdir -p ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR}
  chmod -R 0755 ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR}
  chown -R ${MYSQL_USER}:${MYSQL_USER} ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR}
}

listen() {
  sed -e "s/^bind-address\(.*\)=.*/bind-address = $1/" -i /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
}

apply_configuration_fixes() {
  # disable error log
  sed 's/^log_error/# log_error/' -i /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

  # Fixing StartUp Porblems with some DNS Situations and Speeds up the stuff
  # http://www.percona.com/blog/2008/05/31/dns-achilles-heel-mysql-installation/
  cat > /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql-skip-name-resolv.cnf <<EOF
[mysqld]
skip_name_resolve
EOF
}

remove_debian_system_maint_password() {
  #
  # the default password for the debian-sys-maint user is randomly generated
  # during the installation of the mysql-server package.
  #
  # Due to the nature of docker we blank out the password such that the maintenance
  # user can login without a password.
  #
  sed 's/password = .*/password = /g' -i /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
}

initialize_mysql_database() {
  # initialize MySQL data directory
  if [ ! -d ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR}/mysql ]; then
    echo "Installing database..."
    mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=mysql >/dev/null 2>&1

    # start mysql server
    echo "Starting MySQL server..."
    /usr/bin/mysqld_safe >/dev/null 2>&1 &

    # wait for mysql server to start (max 30 seconds)
    timeout=30
    echo -n "Waiting for database server to accept connections"
    while ! /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root status >/dev/null 2>&1
    do
      timeout=$(($timeout - 1))
      if [ $timeout -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -e "\nCould not connect to database server. Aborting..."
        exit 1
      fi
      echo -n "."
      sleep 1
    done
    echo

    ## create a localhost only, debian-sys-maint user
    ## the debian-sys-maint is used while creating users and database
    ## as well as to shut down or starting up the mysql server via mysqladmin
    echo "Creating debian-sys-maint user..."
    mysql -uroot -e "CREATE USER 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';"
    mysql -uroot -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION;"

    echo "Updating root user..."
    mysql -uroot -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"

    if [ -n "${DB_REMOTE_ROOT_NAME}" -a -n "${DB_REMOTE_ROOT_HOST}" ]; then
      echo "Creating remote user \"${DB_REMOTE_ROOT_NAME}\" with root privileges..."
      mysql -uroot \
      -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '${DB_REMOTE_ROOT_NAME}'@'${DB_REMOTE_ROOT_HOST}' IDENTIFIED BY '${DB_REMOTE_ROOT_PASS}' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
    fi

    /usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf shutdown
  fi
}

create_users_and_databases() {
  # create new user / database
  if [ -n "${DB_USER}" -o -n "${DB_NAME}" ]; then
    /usr/bin/mysqld_safe >/dev/null 2>&1 &

    # wait for mysql server to start (max 30 seconds)
    timeout=30
    echo "Trying to connect to mysql server..."
    while ! /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root -proot status >/dev/null 2>&1
    do
      timeout=$(($timeout - 1))
      if [ $timeout -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Could not connect to mysql server. Aborting..."
        exit 1
      fi
      sleep 1
    done

    if [ -n "${DB_NAME}" ]; then
      for db in $(awk -F',' '{for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++) print $i}' <<< "${DB_NAME}"); do
        echo "Creating database \"$db\"..."
        mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf \
          -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$db\` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET \`$MYSQL_CHARSET\` COLLATE \`$MYSQL_COLLATION\`;"
          if [ -n "${DB_USER}" ]; then
            echo "Granting access to database \"$db\" for user \"${DB_USER}\"..."
            mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf \
            -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`$db\`.* TO '${DB_USER}' IDENTIFIED BY '${DB_PASS}';"
          fi
        done
    fi
    /usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf shutdown
  fi
}

create_data_dir
create_run_dir
create_log_dir

# allow arguments to be passed to mysqld_safe
if [[ ${1:0:1} = '-' ]]; then
  EXTRA_ARGS="$@"
  set --
elif [[ ${1} == mysqld_safe || ${1} == $(which mysqld_safe) ]]; then
  EXTRA_ARGS="${@:2}"
  set --
fi

# default behaviour is to launch mysqld_safe
if [[ -z ${1} ]]; then
  listen "127.0.0.1"
  apply_configuration_fixes
  remove_debian_system_maint_password
  initialize_mysql_database
  create_users_and_databases
  listen "0.0.0.0"
  exec $(which mysqld_safe) $EXTRA_ARGS
else
  exec "$@"
fi
```

*And rabbit-entrypoint.sh:*

```
#!/bin/sh
tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.rabbitmq.list <<EOF
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian bionic erlang
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian bionic main
EOF
## Update package indices
apt-get update -y
## Install rabbitmq-server and its dependencies
apt-get install rabbitmq-server -y --fix-missing
gosu rabbitmq rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_management
```

I've skimmed SO, but could not find anything remotely pertaining to my issue.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried installing it the way that the [official mysql image](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/c506174eab8ae160f56483e8d72410f8f1e1470f/8.0/Dockerfile.debian#L67) does it?

Comment: The missing bit, apart from the "don't do it" aspect about it not being the best practice, is the configuration of supervised to start each of the entrypoints. Random question, why is 18.04 so important here?

Comment: Standard practice would be to use a tool like Docker Compose to run multiple separate containers; then you'd be able to use the standard Docker Hub `mysql` and `rabbitmq` images, without trying to recreate their (involved) setup sequences.  You say you've tried this already; why do you need this specific custom image?

Comment: @DavidMaze This custom image would also contain 2 microservices as well (One spring-boot and a fast API). I need to be able to take the resultant image and upload to the docker hub. This would sort of serve as a single machine environment for the end-user to play with.

Comment: @danblack It's just that, I've been working on ubuntu 18. Although it's not set in stone and the version can be bumped to 20.04 as well.

Comment: You can give the end user the `docker-compose.yml` file, with `image:` lines pointing at the Docker Hub images and the two separate images for the microservices.  Compose is a pretty standard tool and as an end user I wouldn't be surprised to see this.